# Area Renderer (Rickshaw)

Tags: area, renderer, rickshaw

I am very new in rickshaw graphics, I have this graph

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
element: document.getElementById("chart"),
width: 900,
height: 500,
renderer: 'area',
stroke: true,
series: [{
   name : "uno", 
   data : data1
  },
  {
   name : "dos", 
   data : data2
  },
  {
   name : "tres", 
   data :data3
  }
 ]
});
```

But the data value of the charts appear one above the other, for example if
the three "y" values are 1, the first one appears in 1, the second in 2 and the third one in 3.

Im not sure what parameters I have to change in order that the three values appears in 1.

Comment: The problem was that i had to define the unstack value to true

`var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
element: document.getElementById("chart"),
width: 900,
height: 500,
renderer: 'area',
unstack : true,
stroke: true,
series: [{
   name : "uno", 
   data : data1
  },
  {
   name : "dos", 
   data : data2
  },
  {
   name : "tres", 
   data :data3
  }
 ]
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i had to define the unstack value to true

`var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
element: document.getElementById("chart"),
width: 900,
height: 500,
renderer: 'area',
unstack : true,
stroke: true,
series: [{
   name : "uno", 
   data : data1
  },
  {
   name : "dos", 
   data : data2
  },
  {
   name : "tres", 
   data :data3
  }
 ]
});`